# Trying to build sqlite3 parameters using variables in python

Tags: python, parameters, sqlite

I am working on a password manager, using python and squlite3. I am new to DB.
I need to pass parameters to the cursor, and I want to do that dynamically.  What I have now:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO  Passwords (TYPE, SITE, LOGIN, MDP, COMMENTS1) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);""",(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5))
```

It works well, but the table (Passwords) and the columns (TYPE, SITE, LOGIN, MDP, COMMENTS1) are hardcoded.
I tried all the variations I have found on the web, but I have not been able to put variables to work.

I wrote an alternative:

```
"INSERT INTO {0} ({1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}) VALUES ({6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10})".format(table, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)
```

The snippet is nice and all, but returns an error with the variable containing the password (sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "4zMB5e$94t"):

I have been stuck for 2 days. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: You should not use `format` to pass values to your query string, this is an SQL Injection risk. You want a hybrid of the two - you have no choice over the column names - they cannot be parameterized, but keep the `?` placeholders for the values

Comment: Something like `"INSERT INTO {0} ({1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)".format(table, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5), (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5))`. If the variable column names are specified by an external user, you should check that the table name and the column/field names match the schema of the database before executing

Comment: *"the columns ... are hardcoded"*: The columns name are also hardcoded in your db table. Where did you see any benefit not to do so? You Second example are far from readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments, all helpful.
I found a way to circumvent my little problem:
1) columns remain hardcoded, they will not change anyway (I can't remember what I had in mind...)
2) the table name remains harcoded too. The selection from the dropdown menu passes through a set of if conditions.
Problem solved, .format dropped. I think it lacks elegance, but it works.

```
    try:

        if table == 'table1':
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table1 (TYPE, SITE, LOGIN, PW, COMMENTS1) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5))
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO complete (LIST) VALUES (?)", (value4,))           
        elif table == 'email':
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO email (TYPE, SITE, LOGIN, PW, COMMENTS1) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5))
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO complete (LIST) VALUES (?)", (value4,))           

        self.connection.commit()
        print("done saving") 

    except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
        print('Record already exists')
```